# Scala: Add a sequence number to duplicate elements in a list

Tags: scala, collections

I have a list and want to add a sequential number to duplicate elements.

```
val lst=List("a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "d", "b","a")
```

The result should be

```
List("a___0", "b___0", "c____0", "b___1", "c____1", "d___0", "b___2","a___1")
```

preserving  the original order.

What I have so far:

```
val lb=new ListBuffer[String]()
for(i<-0 to lst.length-2) {
  val lbSplit=lb.map(a=>a.split("____")(0)).distinct.toList
  if(!lbSplit.contains(lst(i))){
    var count=0
    lb+=lst(i)+"____"+count

    for(j<-i+1 to lst.length-1){
      if(lst(i).equalsIgnoreCase(lst(j))) {
        count+=1
        lb+= lst(i)+"____"+count
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which results in :

```
res120: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]
  = ListBuffer(a____0, a____1, b____0, b____1, b____2, c____0, c____1, d____0)
```

messing up the order. Also if there is a more concise way that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

This should work without any mutable variables.

```
val lst=List("a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "d", "b","a")

lst.foldLeft((Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0),List[String]())){
  case ((m, l), x) => (m + (x->(m(x)+1)), x + "__" + m(x) :: l)
}._2.reverse
// res0: List[String] = List(a__0, b__0, c__0, b__1, c__1, d__0, b__2, a__1)
```

**explanation**

- `lst.foldLeft` - Take the `List` of items (in this case a `List[String]`) and fold them (starting on the left) into a single item.
- `(Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0),List[String]())` - In this case the new item will be a tuple of type `(Map[String,Int], List[String])`. We'll start the tuple with an empty `Map` and an empty `List`.
- `case ((m, l), x) =>` - Every time an element from `lst` is passed in to the tuple calculation we'll call that element `x`. We'll also receive the tuple from the previous calculation. We'll call the `Map` part `m` and we'll call the `List` part `l`.
- `m + (x->(m(x)+1))` - The `Map` part of the new tuple is created by creating/updating the count for this `String` (the `x`) and adding it to the received `Map`.
- `x + "__" + m(x) :: l` - The `List` part of the new tuple is created by pre-pending a new `String` at the head.
- `}._2.reverse` - The `fold` is finished. Extract the `List` from the tuple (the 2nd element) and reverse it to restore the original order of elements.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the solution?

Comment: A follow question if you don't mind, is it possible to leave the first occurrence of a string without appending __0 at the end? especially since some entries don't have duplication.

Comment: Explanation added. There are a few different ways to add your modification request. The easiest might be to `map` over the current result and strip away all the `"__0"` parts of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more concise way that preserves the order would just to be to use a `Map[String, Int]` to keep a running total of each time you've seen a particular string. Then you can just map over `lst` directly and keep updating the map each time you've seen a string:

```
var map = Map[String, Int]()
lst.map { str =>
  val count = map.getOrElse(str, 0) //get current count if in the map, otherwise zero
  map += (str -> (count + 1)) //update the count
  str + "__" + count
}
```

which will give you the following for your example:

```
List(a__0, b__0, c__0, b__1, c__1, d__0, b__2, a__1)
```

I consider that easiest to read, but if you want to avoid `var` then you can use `foldLeft` with a tuple to hold the intermediate state of the map:

```
lst.foldLeft((List[String](), Map[String, Int]())) { case ((list, map), str) =>
  val count = map.getOrElse(str, 0)
  (list :+ (str + "__" + count), map + (str -> (count + 1)))
}._1
```